# Rails: Can't load mages from assets in 'edit view'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, assets

Ok so I have a rails app where I have images in **app/public/logo**, I can load these images from any views of my app, for example I'm loading these images in **app/views/pins/_form.html.erb**

But I can't load these images in **app/views/pins/edit.html.erb** and instead I have broken images.

Any ideas why I am encoutering this bug ? I had this for all my rails project, I was always used to find ways to avoid rendering images from the edit views, but today I am really asking myself why this is not working ? Any ideas ?

Comment: You need to provide some code mate, I have no idea what the difference is between your two views. Also you should probably be using the asset pipeline for images http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: You should be putting your images in the asset pipeline. Put the image in app/assets/images and call it in the view using <%= image_tag asset_path('your_image.jpg') %>. That should work. Or some variation of that.

Answer (score 0):

if you have an image in : app/assets/images/   named: logo.png

you would use:

```
<%=image_tag( 'logo.png')%>
```

or make it a link:

```
<%= link_to image_tag( 'logo.png'),'/'%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Was having the same problem. Make sure your image is in the public/assets/images folder. Now use this code to access it.

`<%= image_tag asset_path('assets/images/beta.png') %>`

Worked for me.